# How to get array output in html table

Tags: php, html, html-table

What I would like to do is the following:

I have an SQL query that give's me an output. On that output 1 make an selection in php.

```
$cities[$row['stad']][$row['status']]++
```

This gives me an output like this (within a `<pre>` tag ):

```
Array
(
    [Amsterdam] => Array
        (
            [41] => 2
            [21] => 91
            [43] => 16
            [42] => 2
            [20] => 30
            [4] => 4
            [70] => 3
            [84] => 8
            [46] => 4
            [45] => 5
            [999] => 26
            [47] => 2
            [3] => 8
            [44] => 1
            [40] => 1
            [93] => 5
            [56] => 3
            [61] => 3
            [79] => 3
            [48] => 2
            [50] => 5
            [10] => 10
            [52] => 2
            [120] => 1
            [95] => 1
            [1] => 65
            [90] => 6
        )
```

I would like to put in an html table like so :

```
City        41  21  43  42  20  7   …… etc 
amsterdam   2   91  16  2   30  4   …… etc
```

important to know is there are more than 1 city.

This is what I have at the moment :

```
echo '<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" border="1">';

foreach($cities as $city) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['stad'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $city[$row['status']] . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: what is the problem you face with this?

Comment: The first row of your table represents the table head ? I mean you put "City" in the first column, but values in others, are these values always the same ?

Comment: the first row does represent  the head of the table it could be that not every city has values on each row but then it is just empty . the value per city is always different

Comment: please can you print what you will get in $city ?

Comment: @rahuls Is there an array that lists all the heading values?

Comment: @Barmar yes what I do is 1 check if the row is not  empty an then I give an output what is in the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another array that lists all the heading values; in my code below I call this array `$headings`. This is because the values for each city may have their keys in a different order, and there may be missing keys, so just looping through the city arrays won't get consistent values on each row.

```
$headings = array(41, 21,  43,  42,  20,  7, etc.); 

echo '<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" border="1">';
echo '<tr><th>City</th>';
foreach ($headings as $h) {
    echo "<th>$h</th>";
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach($cities as $cityname => $city) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>$cityname</td>";
    foreach ($headings as $h) {
        echo '<td>' . (isset($city[$h]) ? $city[$h] : '') . '</td>';
    }    
    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';
```

Comment: this gives me an output with just a table with the word  city in it

Comment: Add `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the beginning, do you get any warnings?

Comment: Yes i did get warnings like 
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/locationboard/index.php on line 55   but I turned of all te errors with    `error_reporting(0);`

Comment: Don't turn off errors when you're trying to debug a script.

Comment: `foreach ($headings as $h) { `

Comment: Did you set `$headings` to the list of all the column names?

Comment: It worked but now I would like to count 41 ,21 ,43  together to one group and put it in 1 column is that possible?

Comment: Sure. See the `array_chunk` function for rearranging an array into groups.

Comment: array_chunk will not work because that will always take the first three values. For instance I would always like to get status 1, 2, 3 (amounts can vary) and count the values in the status together but it can be that status 2 does not exist.

Comment: I was thinking that you would use `array_chunk` on the `$headings` array, so it will be grouped the same for all rows.

Comment: The problem is that the amount of rows can be different. For example I would like to take the first 3 values of the array and then 4th and 5th. with array chucks I can put just 1 value

Comment: I'm not really understanding what you want to do with these groups. This probably needs to be a new question, so you can show what you want the new table to look like.

Comment: I posted a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34681247/counting-values-in-array

Answer (score 0):

Simply use a `foreach` on the array to build your table.

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($cities as $key => $value): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $key; ?>
            <?php foreach ($value as $subkey => $subvalue): ?>
                <td><?= $subvalue; ?> </td>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In steps:

- Loop through all cities
- Since every city has its own sub array, we will then loop through that array

Answer (score 0):

use foreach with $key element so you get key directly into it

change this code

```
foreach($cities as $city) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['stad'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $city[$row['status']] . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

to

```
foreach($cities as $key=> $city) { 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $key. '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $city . '</td>';

    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this -

```
<?php
echo '<table cellpadding="10" cellspacing="10" border="1">';
foreach($cities as $city):
foreach($city as $k => $v)
{
echo "<tr><td>$k</td><td>$v</td></tr>";
}
endforeach;
?>
```

Comment: This will put each key and value on a separate row, instead of having all the values for a city on the same row.

Comment: That is true I tried to run it but it gives me an output like  @Barmar  predicted