# Counting values in array

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get values from this array and counting them. Let's say we have Amsterdam and I would like to count value [41, 21, 43] together and put them in a html table. The problem is that the values sometimes miss as you can see below. How can I achieve this?

```
Array
(
    [Amsterdam] => Array
        (
            [41] => 2
            [21] => 91
            [43] => 16
            [42] => 2
            [20] => 30
            [4] => 4
            [70] => 3
            [84] => 8
            [46] => 4
            [45] => 5
            [999] => 26
            [47] => 2
            [3] => 8
            [44] => 1
            [40] => 1
            [93] => 5
            [56] => 3
            [61] => 3
            [79] => 3
            [48] => 2
            [50] => 5
            [10] => 10
            [52] => 2
            [120] => 1
            [95] => 1
            [1] => 64
            [90] => 4
            [100] => 2
            [101] => 1
        )

    [Rotterdam] => Array
        (
            [21] => 42
            [41] => 2
            [42] => 2
            [46] => 1
            [47] => 2
            [43] => 4
            [45] => 3
            [4] => 1
            [3] => 19
            [84] => 1
            [12] => 1
            [20] => 14
            [40] => 1
            [48] => 6
            [61] => 1
            [52] => 1
            [10] => 4
            [1] => 23
            [90] => 2
        )

    [Spaarnwoude] => Array
        (
            [21] => 2
        )
```

This is what I already tried:

```
  foreach ($headings as $h) {
        echo "<th>$h</th>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';

    foreach($cities as $cityname => $city) { 
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>$cityname</td>";
        foreach (array_chunk($headings, 3) as $h) {
            echo '<td>' . (isset($city[$h]) ? $city[$h] : '0') . '</td>';
        }    
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';
```

For further information you can check this link.

[How to get array output in html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34675118/how-to-get-array-output-in-html-table)

Comment: did you check the [array_key_exists](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) function?

Comment: Just get the keys of your subArray and sum them together

Comment: @rahul s, do you want to sum only specific key values or all of them?

Comment: Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You need to provide the code you've written to try to solve the problem, so we can help you fix it instead of writing it for you. Also, show what the desired result is -- I told you to do that in the last question when I said to ask a new question.

Comment: How do you determine which values should be counted together? Why just `[41, 21, 43]`?

Comment: What do you mean by counting the values together? Do you mean we should add `2+91+16` and display `109` for that group?

Comment: @Barmar I don't think it's correct or helpful to tell the OP that they must show the code they've written so far; not all questions have to be debugging questions, and asking "how can I do X" is perfectly reasonable as long as X is well-specified and something that somebody else might conceivably want to do. This question is unanswerable garbage, but it's unanswerable garbage because what needs to be done isn't clearly specified (as you've already noted); adding a code dump that does *something* and fails to achieve the (probably trivial) desired result would only make things worse.

Comment: @MarkAmery First, we want posters to show some initiative of trying to solve the problem themselves before the post a question. Second, the code they try to write will often help understand the question when they have a hard time describing it.

Comment: @MarkAmery first of all thank you for your feedback. The problem is that I don't now what code is to solve the problem. If i would know what the problem/code was I wouldn't ask a question.

Comment: @Barmar I have just edited the code above and the question **Do you mean we should add 2+91+16 and display 109 for that group?** is correct I would like to get that as a result

Comment: You're missing the second argument to `array_chunk`, to say how big the chunks should be.

Comment: That is where my problem is because sometimes i would like to take the first 3 columns and count them and then i would like to get the 4th and 5th column  together .  so the number of columns witch I want to count is every time different

Comment: That's what I asked before: how does the script know which columns should be grouped together?

Comment: If it's different every time, where does that information come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need another level of looping for each heading in the chunks.

```
$chunked_headings = array_chunk($headings, 3);
echo '<tr>';
foreach ($chunked_headings as $heading_group) {
    echo '<th>' . implode(', ', $heading_group) . '</th>';
}
echo '</tr>';

foreach ($cities as $cityname => $city) {
    echo '<tr>';
    echo "<td>$cityname</td>";
    foreach ($chunked_headings as $heading_group) {
        $total = 0;
        foreach ($heading_group as $h) {
            if (isset($city[$h])) {
                $total += $city[$h];
            }
        }
        echo "<td>$total</td>";
    }
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly thank you for your help

Comment: There is still a little question witch is what if the array chuck are different numbers for example first I want to have 3  chunks and then 2 and then 4 etc. Is it possible to get an counter instead of the 3

Comment: I keep asking you where those groupings come from, you don't answer!

Comment: Instead of using `array_chunk`, you can use some other method to create the `$chunked_headings` array. That will define how the columns are grouped.

Comment: You can use a variable instead of `3`. So if the size of the group comes from the user, you can do that.

Comment: Those groupings are in an array but it could also be in a string, var etc .

Comment: I'm getting very tired of this. Whatever criteria you want to use, you can use it to fill in `$chunked_headings`. Do it however you want.